# UITableView scroll to the bottom messed up with EstimatedRowHeight

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to scroll to the bottom of my UITableView (commentsFeed) whenever the user creates a new comment or the user refreshes the UITableView.

The code I use is:

```
func scrollToBottomOfComments() {

    var lastRowNumber = commentsFeed.numberOfRowsInSection(0) - 1
    var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: lastRowNumber, inSection: 0)
    commentsFeed.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
}
```

The problem is here in `viewDidLoad`:

```
commentsFeed.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
commentsFeed.estimatedRowHeight = 150
```

This basically states that the comments can have dynamic heights because users could post either really long comments or really short comments.

When I use the estimatedRowHeight, my `scrollToBottom` doesn't properly scroll to the bottom because it basically assumes my table height is `commentsFeed.count * commentsFeed.estimatedRowHeight`

This isn't correct though.

When I remove the `estimatedRowHeight` though, it doesn't seem to work either, and I think the reason is because it doesn't have the row height calculated properly because the rows each have dynamic heights.

How do I mitigate this?

**Edit: It should be stated that the scroll doesn't end up at the right position, but the moment I use my finger to scroll anywhere, then the data jumps into place where it should have been via the scroll**

Comment: I have a question. Is there any specific reason that you use estimated size in viewDidLoad, instead of calculating the real height of content when tableView actually draws it ?

Comment: @bllakjakk I've never managed to successfully ping for the height in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. The first time around, it is always 0 for me, and then othertimes it is always of the dequeued cell (the contents I'm changing because this new data is coming into view). Perhaps I have never done it correctly though

Comment: Would you share some test code where this issue can be reproduced. Let me try to help you fix it. Should be some trivial issue, as this works like charm in our chat application. BTW I added a sample solution below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you calculate the real size of row by something similar to below method.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomObject *message = [list.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //fontChat not available yet

    NSMutableAttributedString *text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:message];
    NSRange all = NSMakeRange(0, text.length);

    [text addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:DEFAULT_FONT size:21] range:all];
    [text addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:RGB(61, 61, 61) range:all];

    CGSize theSize = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(200, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil].size;


    if (theSize.height == 0) {
        theSize.height = FIXED_SIZE;
    }

    return theSize.height;
}
```

Now for scrolling, I use the following source:
Check it out.

```
-(void) scrollTolastRow
{
    if (self.tableView.contentSize.height > self.tableView.frame.size.height)
    {
        CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.frame.size.height);
        [self.tableView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is COText? I can't seem to ping it.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple things that could be affecting your outcome, but it's most likely that *your estimated height is not a great estimate*. In my experience, anything not particularly close to the true height of the cells will cause havoc on animations. In your case, you mention that the content are comments, or free-form text. I would guess that these cell heights vary wildly, and depending on how your cell is composed, you're probably not going to be able to provide a very accurate estimate, and so you should not provide one. For a large number of cells, this is going to hurt performance, but you probably don't have a choice. Instead, you might want to shift your focus to how you can page in/page out cells into your table to avoid costly calculations, or rearrange your cell to be able to calculate a better estimate. Another suggestion might be to implement `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` with an accurate but still less complex algorithm for calculating the height. In any event, *a constant value for an estimatedRowHeight will likely **never** work when you support DynamicType*. At the very least, you need to take into account the current DynamicType size.

Other than that, what can you do? Instead of using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, consider implementing `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and calculating the height of your displayed strings **and caching the result** (you could use an `NSIndexPath -> NSNumber` `NSCache` object). You need to cache the result because without an `estimatedHeight`, `heightForRow` is called once for every row when the table is loaded, and then once for every cell as it appears on screen. When using `estimatedHeight` on iOS 8, `estimatedHeight` is called once for each cell on launch and `heightForRow` is called as the cells appear. This is where the estimate is critical, because that is what's used to calculate the `contentSize` of the `UITableView`'s backing `UIScrollView`. If the estimated size is wrong, the `contentSize` is wrong, and so when you ask the tableView to scroll to the last cell, the frame of the last cell is calculated with the bad estimate, which gives you the incorrect `contentOffset`. Unfortunately, I *believe* (based on the behavior I see trying to reproduce your question) that when you use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` without an estimate, the runtime implicitly estimates an estimate.

Comment: My issue with `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is that it doesn't know the height the dynamic height the first time around. Once the height is known, it will use that value, but the first time around (the important time... to set the cache), it doesn't know what the height is. Further, what do you think about the fact that it doesn't scroll properly, but the moment I use my finger to scroll after the in-correct `scrollToBottom()` it quickly fixes itself to the bottom. I don't understand what is happening internally that yields inaccurate scroll, but accurate offset after I try to scroll.

Comment: `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is a method you must implement. I'm assuming your cells are just a UILabel with some padding around it. You'd add the height of the padding to the height of the string you need to represent (`boundingRectWithSize:options:context`). As far as the tapping making the table scroll to the bottom, I didn't experience this when I was testing, but perhaps the actual heights for all the cells are being calculated in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and the `contentSize` is being invalidated and laid out again.

Comment: `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is no longer needed on iOS 8.

Comment: @greg "At the very least, you need to take into account the current DynamicType size". Can you expound on this a little more, or provide an example?

Comment: @SAHM If your `estimatedHeight` message is as simple as `return (42)`, it will often be wrong if you're supporting DynamicType. With DynamicType, you don't know the user's current font size setting, and depending on their setting, the height of your row will change. At a minimum, you need to detect the user's setting and compensate. For instance, you might find that at `UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityMedium` your row should be `42`, but at `UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge`, it must be `100`. These values differ too greatly to be useful (see first sentence of answer).

Answer (score 1):

EstimatedRowHeight is used by UIKit to estimate whole contentSize (and scrollIndicatorInset), so if you add new row at the end with automatic row dimension, you have to reset estimatedRowHeight to actual average value of whole tableView before you animate scroll.

This is not so good solution because its lot easier to count row height in old style - manually. Or add new cell height value to old table view's content height.

But because you adding new row at the **end** of table, you can scroll at middle or top position, which ends up with the bottom position, because there is contentInset.bottom = 0. And also the animation will look better.

So:

```
commentsFeed.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .**Middle**, animated: true)
```

Its look like in .Middle and .Top positions is some condition under the hood in animation which prevent to make a gap between bottom edge and table view's content (+ contentInset.bottom)

P.S. **Why not to use the manuall row height calculation?**

Because there is autolayout and I believe the "auto" is shortcut for automatic. And also it will save your time and troubles with custom fonts, attributed string, combined cell with more labels and other subviews and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Try this, works for me:

```
NSMutableArray *visibleCellIndexPaths = [[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] mutableCopy];


[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:visibleCellIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];

[self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.bounds.size.height, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, self.tableView.bounds.size.height) animated:YES];
```